# MySQL - Selecting the next item in a sequence based on previous sequences

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that stores values if they have appeared together in a sequence. For example:

```
value_a | value_b | count
-------------------------
   1    |   2     |   5
   1    |   3     |   4
   2    |   3     |   7
```

The count stores the number of times `value_b` has been seen following `value_a`. Using this, I can create a probability-based sequence. For example I can pick any random value to start the sequence - in this case, *1* -  and select the values that have followed it before:

```
> SELECT value_b FROM values WHERE value = 1

value_b
-------
   2
   3
```

My sequence is now *1, 2*

What I'd like to do is add an additional lookup. Once I have a value - *2* in this case - I want to select any values that followed it, but only in the sequence I already have:

```
SELECT value_b FROM values WHERE value = 2 
AND 
* magic line to only include to cases where 2 also followed 1 *
```

Can this be done without changing the schema, or have I already lost the information I need (as I suspect)?

If I do need to alter the schema to add an extra dimension, can it be structured in a way to be able to look back 3 or more levels in a simple way?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not another join on the value table like

```
select v1.value_b, v2.value_b from values v1
inner/left join values v2 on v1.value_2=v2.value_1
where v1.value_1=1
```

You would need to use left/inner, dependent if you want or don't want lines where no next value is found. If you need more than one iteration you need to use more joins.

Comment: This is showing some promise, thanks - the LEFT join is the one I want, since I only want a value if the previous sequence has already been seen. If I want multiple joins do I have to add in a GROUP BY?

Answer (score 0):

This will get a three value sequence starting with a particular value. Remove the WHERE clause to get a complete list of all 3 value sequences. It will not show any sequences with less than or more than 3 values.

```
SELECT
    a.`value_a` as `seq_1`,
    a.`value_b` as `seq_2`,
    b.`value_b` as `seq_3`
FROM `values` a
JOIN `values` b
ON a.`value_b` = b.`value_a`
WHERE a.`value_a` = 1
GROUP BY a.`value_a`, a.`value_b`, b.`value_b`
ORDER BY a.`value_a`, a.`value_b`, b.`value_b`;
```

Comment: Thanks - can this be altered to read in reverse, so starting with the last two values I have, to select the next value?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean